# Getting the column names of the selected row in SQL?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a program with 2 forms and both forms have their own grid. Grid1 is on form1, Grid2 is on form2. I want Grid2 to serve as a pop up window which is used for editing. When a user doubleclicks a row on Grid1, it should do a requery on just that row and display that single row on Grid2. I can't figure out how to get the column names of the selectedrow then do a query on it's unique identifers. What I have so far:
(This is on form1 by the way)

```
 Public Sub dgvForm1_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvForm1.CellDoubleClick

Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim rowIndex As Integer
Dim cellName as string



While dgvForm1.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(i).ColumnIndex < dgvForm1.ColumnCount

      rowIndex = dgvForm1.SelectedRows.Item(0).HeaderCell.RowIndex
      cellName = dgvForm1.SelectedRows.Item(0).HeaderCell.toString 
      Select Case cellName
             Case "control_no"
                 Dim sControlNum = cellName.ToString
             Case "store_id"
                 Dim sStoreNum = cellName.ToString
      End Select

      i = i + 1
End While
end sub
```

I simply just want the user to doubleclick a row that is displayed on a datagridview with many other records, and that triggers a doubleclick event. This would then loop through the selectedrow's column names until it finds both control_id and store_id and gets their values. P.s. I tried google for a good hour or so but I had a hard time getting any techniques to work.

UPDATE:
   I should probably add, this is a bound datagrid that uses sqlClient and its dataadapter/dataset method.

Comment: If anyone is aware of a similar post, by all means have this post closed and point me to an existing one! I looked but could not find one that I knew how to implement their solution to my code.

Comment: What you should have googled for is something with "datatable" in it.  You see, DataSet is a class from Dotnet1 and it contains many methods and properties.  If you decide to inherit from it to refine it further you get even more stuff, like events IIRC.  But please beware - you are using TableAdapter and that is an old technique seldom used any more.  (To make things more hard to grasp DataSet is also frowned upon IMHO because people have misunderstood the difference between DataSet, Typed DataSet and TableAdapters.  IMHO: TableAdapers:bad, DataSet:untyped and hence bad, Typed DataSet:good.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myTable.Columns.ColumnName.
Read more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnname.aspx

Comment: This should be a simple comment, not an answer. Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Thx for your input.  Made the answer more answer like.